# AWS EBS read bandwidth Under-provisioned Question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Aws, recently I checked my Compute Optimizer

found the following:

"Compute Optimizer found that this instance's EBS throughput is under-provisioned."
EBS read bandwidth (MiB/second)
EBS write bandwidth (MiB/second)
both Under-provisioned from AWS Compute Optimizer.

I am not so sure how to increase, AWS Compute Optimizer showed few different instance type to switch from, but there is no information about the EBS read and write bandwidth.

There is a tab for **instance** and **Attached EBS volumes**. So should I update the instance with the recommend one or update the EBS volumes, which one will increase the EBS read/write bandwidth?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type of instance and what type of volume are we talking about?

Comment: It is the General Purpose SSD (gp2), 8GB, it is aws free tier. EC2 t2.micro.

Comment: It's unclear from what you've written here whether the issue is networking bandwidth or IOPS, but with an 8GB volume I suspect the latter. Look at the CloudWatch metrics for the volume to see if it's up against the limit or not. You can increase the volume size (if gp2) or change to gp3 to get more bandwidth (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html#gp3-ebs-volume-type)). **But be aware that you will be charged for anything not covered by the free tier.**

Answer (score 0):

This message means the EC2 instance cannot send out the data fast enough. It normally happens when you have several EBS volumes, and together they can accept data faster than the EC2 instance can transmit it.

I agree the optimizer recommendations are confusing, since they do not show you the EBS throughput from the different recommendations. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html (if you scroll right in the embedded tables) shows the througput supported by the ec2 instance - you need enough to push data to all your EBS volumes.